# CalendarApp.getAllCalendars() returns array of nulls

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm calling CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()
on the server via a call on the client

```
/*- server  code-*/
function getCalendars(){
 return CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
}
/*-*/

/*-client code-*/
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getCalendarsHandler).getCalendars();

getCalendarsHandler=function(cals){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(cals));
};
/*-*/
```

console shows...
[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]

getCalendarsHandler receives an array of the correct length (i.e. the number of calendars I have access too)
but each element in that array is null,
could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

later that day.....

on further investigation it looks like I'll have to build the structure on the server before passing it to the client. I was expecting something similar to gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list(); but it looks like I'll have to build my own - something like....

```
function getCalendars()
{
 var cal,i,resp;
 resp=[];
 cal=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
 for(i=0;i<cal.length;i++)
 {
  resp[i]={
   "name":cal[i].getName(),
   "id":cal[i].getId()
    ...
  }
 }
 return resp;
}
```

Comment: That's right. You can not pass any object between Apps Script server and client sides. Only regular JS objects with strings, numbers, booleans, etc. Also, you should answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, as I was new to stackoverlflow - it wouldn't let me answer my own question so I had to edit the original question with my 'later that day' comment. I'll try again to mark the question as answered....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

later that day.....

on further investigation it looks like I'll have to build the structure on the server before passing it to the client. I was expecting something similar to gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list(); but it looks like I'll have to build my own - something like....

```
function getCalendars()
{
 var cal,i,resp;
 resp=[];
 cal=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
 for(i=0;i<cal.length;i++)
 {
  resp[i]={
   "name":cal[i].getName(),
   "id":cal[i].getId()
    ...
  }
 }
 return resp;
}
```